# My site is pushed to the left side when resized to the mobile mode

Tags: mobile, responsiveness

Page pushed to the left and title section pushing the width of the page. I'm new to web Dev, So please let me know where I made the mistake and how to correct it. Full CSS and HTML codes included. Bootstrap version 4. This is a personal blog, my am was to make each post page responsive the same way the homepage made responsive. I can't figure out how to do it. [Red arrows show where it pushed to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpvOw.png)

https://github.com/GreshanBovithanthrige/Personal-Blog.git

Git Hub Repo link

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  color: #000;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

#title {
  background-color: #082032;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
}

.gb-img {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5% 0%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* display: flex; */

}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 3% 15%;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000;
}

h2 {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

p {
  color: #40514E;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
.navbar {
  padding-bottom: 4.5rem;
}

.navbar-brand {
  font-family: "Alumni Sans";
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 2.7rem;
}

.nav-item {
  padding: 0 18px;
}

.nav-link {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-weight: 300;
}

/* Buttons */
.about-button {
  margin: 2% 0% 5% 0%;
}

.card-button {
  width: 180px;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Features Secition */
#features {
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

.feature-box {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5%;
}

.card {
  background-color: #212529;
  border-radius: .50rem;
}

.card-text {
  color: #fff;
}

.card-title {
  color: #fff;
}

.post-column {
  padding-bottom: 5%;
}

/* Footer */
#footer {
  padding: 7% 15%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #334756;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.p-text {
  color: #fff;
}

.sm-icon {
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

/* About me page styles */
.about-page-p {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  padding-left: 30%;
  padding-right: 30%;
}

/* Posts Section  */
/* Post 1 */
.post1 {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 7% 15%;
}

.office-image {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 3% 0%;
}

/* Post 2 */
.post2 {
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 7% 15%;
}



@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) {
/* .row {
  position: relative;
 } */

.container-fluid{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.common{
  margin: auto;
  padding-left: 12%;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

body{
  padding:0%;
}



}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>GB</title>
  <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="images/GB.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&family=Ubuntu:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alumni+Sans:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">



</head>

<body>

  <section id="title">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Nav Bar -->
      <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark navbar">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">GB</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Posts</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="about-me.html">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#footer">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>


    <!-- Title -->

    <!-- <div class="row"> -->

    <div class="section">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm">
            <h1>Hello.</h1>
            <h2>I'm Greshan Bovithanthrige</h2>
            <h4>A Sys Admin based in Sri Lanka</h4>
            <a href="about-me.html" type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg about-button about-me-button">About me</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm row common">
            <img src="images/GB.png" height="280" width="280">
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div> -->

  </section>



  <section id="features">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 post-column">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image-gmfl.png" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">All of us in whatever context is tasked with getting more from less!</h5>
            <p class="card-text">The energy behind writing this article came from an interview I had the privilege to watch recently.</p>
          </div>
          <a href="post1.html" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm card-button">Read More</a>
          <div class="card-footer">
            <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 post-column"">
        <div class=" card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/RAM.jpeg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Is it necessary to stress test your RAM/Memory?</h5>
          <p class="card-text">The short answer is YES. You should. But, it really depends on the context.</p>
        </div>
        <a href="post2.html" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm card-button">Read More</a>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 post-column"">
        <div class=" card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image-gmfl.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
        <p class="card-text">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book. </p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm card-button">Read More</a>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </section>


  <section id="features">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 post-column"">
        <div class=" card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image-gmfl.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
          <p class="card-text">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
            make a type specimen book. </p>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm card-button">Read More</a>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 post-column"">
        <div class=" card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image-gmfl.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
        <p class="card-text">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book. </p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm card-button">Read More</a>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 post-column"">
        <div class=" card">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/image-gmfl.png" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing</h5>
        <p class="card-text">orem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to
          make a type specimen book. </p>
      </div>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm card-button">Read More</a>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </section>




  <!-- Footer -->

  <footer id="footer">
    <a href="https://facebook.com/GreshanBovithanthrige"><span style="color:#FFF;"><span /><i class="fab fa-facebook sm-icon"></i></a>
    <a href="https://instagram.com/gbovithanthrige"><span style="color:#FFF;"><span /><i class="fab fa-instagram sm-icon"></i><a />
        <a href="https://twitter.com/gbovithanthrige"><span style="color:#FFF;"><span /><i class="fab fa-twitter sm-icon"></i><a />
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/greshanbovithanthrige/"><span style="color:#FFF;"><span /><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in sm-icon"></i></a>
            <a href="mailto:greshanbovithanthrige@gmail.com"><span style="color:#FFF;"><span /><i class="fas fa-envelope-square sm-icon"></i></a>

            <p class="p-text">Crafted by Greshan Bovithanthrige</p>

  </footer>


</body>

</html>
```